# Insert pandas dataframe as dataset in HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I ran into an issue of pandas HDFStore method, where I can't access the data in a way I use to retrieve using h5py.File method. Here is the code snippet:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd  

In [2]: import numpy as np  

In [3]: import h5py as h5

In [4]: hdf = pd.HDFStore("tmp.h5")

In [5]: hdf.put('tables/t1', pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,5)))

In [6]: hdf.put('t2', pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5)))

In [7]: 

In [7]: hdf.close() 

In [8]: 

In [8]: ############ Read using pd.HDFStore ############

In [9]: 

In [9]: data = pd.HDFStore ("tmp.h5") 

In [10]: data["tables/t1"] 
Out[10]: 
           0         1         2         3         4
0   0.384926  0.712066  0.022438  0.686217  0.942678
1   0.079548  0.466799  0.575394  0.276646  0.514414
2   0.672582  0.828567  0.801799  0.296046  0.124042
3   0.568058  0.931348  0.225348  0.547913  0.736184
4   0.496768  0.419699  0.724118  0.313427  0.353825
5   0.771868  0.963346  0.523821  0.793295  0.052085
6   0.358478  0.845149  0.334389  0.674448  0.239096
7   0.454559  0.604438  0.183654  0.027641  0.186922
8   0.776586  0.155783  0.253801  0.123986  0.560601
9   0.201239  0.932080  0.040997  0.119049  0.154076
10  0.753566  0.770133  0.123285  0.112419  0.353622
11  0.040959  0.384800  0.806119  0.247106  0.013442
12  0.739205  0.100547  0.855418  0.774874  0.710557
13  0.865856  0.565094  0.815860  0.816869  0.834415
14  0.251312  0.624995  0.976317  0.854855  0.744861
15  0.179678  0.435902  0.602303  0.118516  0.386935
16  0.452009  0.973729  0.067736  0.097811  0.292619
17  0.285994  0.569845  0.584602  0.001671  0.422877
18  0.727996  0.291086  0.736912  0.960595  0.132891
19  0.356397  0.747693  0.458485  0.100849  0.072220

In [11]: ## Success 

In [12]: data ["tables"]["t1"] 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c7599d16a7b6> in <module>()
----> 1 data ["tables"]["t1"]

/usr/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    415 
    416     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 417         return self.get(key)
    418 
    419     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

/usr/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in get(self, key)
    632         if group is None:
    633             raise KeyError('No object named %s in the file' % key)
--> 634         return self._read_group(group)
    635 
    636     def select(self, key, where=None, start=None, stop=None, columns=None,

/usr/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in _read_group(self, group, **kwargs)
   1268 
   1269     def _read_group(self, group, **kwargs):
-> 1270         s = self._create_storer(group)
   1271         s.infer_axes()
   1272         return s.read(**kwargs)

/usr/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in _create_storer(self, group, format, value, append, **kwargs)
   1151                 else:
   1152                     raise TypeError(
-> 1153                         "cannot create a storer if the object is not existing "
   1154                         "nor a value are passed")
   1155             else:

TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed

In [13]: 

In [13]: data.close() 

In [14]: 

In [14]: ########### Read using h5py.File ############## 

In [15]: 

In [15]: data = h5.File("tmp.h5","r") 

In [16]: 

In [16]: data["tables"]
Out[16]: <HDF5 group "/tables" (1 members)>

In [17]: 

In [17]: data["tables"]["t1"]
Out[17]: <HDF5 group "/tables/t1" (4 members)>

In [18]: 

In [18]: data['tables']['t1'].keys ()
Out[18]: [u'axis0', u'axis1', u'block0_items', u'block0_values']

In [19]: [u'axis0', u'axis1', u'block0_items', u'block0_values']
Out[19]: [u'axis0', u'axis1', u'block0_items', u'block0_values']

In [20]: 

In [20]: data['tables']['t1']['block0_values'].value
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0.38492571,  0.71206567,  0.02243773,  0.68621713,  0.9426783 ],
       [ 0.07954806,  0.4667994 ,  0.57539433,  0.27664603,  0.51441446],
       [ 0.67258161,  0.82856681,  0.80179916,  0.29604625,  0.12404214],
       [ 0.56805845,  0.93134797,  0.22534757,  0.54791294,  0.73618366],
       [ 0.49676792,  0.41969943,  0.72411835,  0.31342698,  0.35382463],
       [ 0.77186804,  0.96334586,  0.52382094,  0.7932945 ,  0.05208528],
       [ 0.3584784 ,  0.84514863,  0.33438851,  0.6744483 ,  0.23909552],
       [ 0.45455901,  0.6044383 ,  0.18365449,  0.02764097,  0.18692162],
       [ 0.77658631,  0.15578276,  0.25380109,  0.12398617,  0.56060138],
       [ 0.20123928,  0.93207974,  0.04099724,  0.11904895,  0.15407568],
       [ 0.75356644,  0.77013349,  0.12328475,  0.11241904,  0.35362213],
       [ 0.04095888,  0.38480023,  0.80611853,  0.24710571,  0.01344193],
       [ 0.73920528,  0.1005474 ,  0.85541761,  0.7748739 ,  0.71055697],
       [ 0.86585587,  0.5650938 ,  0.81586031,  0.81686915,  0.83441517],
       [ 0.25131205,  0.62499501,  0.97631707,  0.85485518,  0.74486096],
       [ 0.17967805,  0.43590236,  0.60230302,  0.11851596,  0.38693535],
       [ 0.4520091 ,  0.97372923,  0.0677363 ,  0.09781059,  0.29261929],
       [ 0.28599448,  0.56984462,  0.5846021 ,  0.00167063,  0.42287738],
       [ 0.72799625,  0.29108631,  0.7369122 ,  0.96059508,  0.13289119],
       [ 0.35639696,  0.7476934 ,  0.45848456,  0.10084881,  0.07221995]])

In [21]: 

In [21]: ######################## End ############### 

In [22]: 

In [22]:
```

I want to use **data['tables']['t1']** way access the data. I am stuck because of this problem. What I observed is that pandas insert every dataframe in hd5 as group. I want to insert it as a dataset, so that I can easily access the data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hierarchical-keys) for `HDFStore`.

> Warning: Hierarchical keys cannot be retrieved as dotted (attribute) access as described above for items stored under the root node. Instead, use explicit string based keys.

So its just a difference in the way the modules load the hdfs.

Comment: Seems like I have to go with old school approach where I create `group` and add `dataset` using `h5py` module. It will be nice to have the asked approach to acccess the data in `pandas` HDFStore.